# How to submit popup form using ajax with page refresh in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, popup

I am trying to submit my popup form with ajax without page reload and my messages sucess and error should be shown on my popup form:

My Ajax code:

```
                  $('#submit_form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/changepassword",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(change_password) {
                alert(change_password);
            }
        });
    }),
```

My Controller code:

```
                   public function changepassword(Request $request){
    $user = Auth::guard()->user();
    $request_data = $request->All();
    $validator = $this->admin_credential_rules($request_data);
    if($validator->fails()) {
        $errors = $validator->errors();
        $errors = json_decode($errors);

        return response()->json([
            'success' => false,
            'message' => $errors
        ], 422);
    } else {

        $current_password = $user->password;
        if(md5($request_data['password']) == $current_password) {
            $user_id = $user->id;
            $obj_user = User::find($user_id);
            $obj_user->password = md5($request_data['new_password']);
            $obj_user->save();

             $msg = "password has been changed";
            return response()->json(array('change_password'=> $msg), 200);
        } else {
            $error = array('error' => array('Heslo, kterÃ© jste zadali, je neplatnÃ©.'));
            return response()->json([
                'modal_message_danger' , "Heslo, které jste zadali, je neplatné.",
                'message' => $error
            ], 422);
        }
    }
}
```

And my popup form:

```
                     <div class="modal fade common_modal" id="change_password" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">Ã—</span></button>
                <h3>ZmÄ›na hesla</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form role="form" id="password_change_form" class="common_form_style popup_form">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="password" style="width:100%">PÅ¯vodnÃ­ heslo </label>
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
                                <span toggle="#password-field" class="fa fa-fw fa-eye field-icon toggle-password"></span>
                            </div>

                            <div class="submit-btn text-center">
                            <button type="submit"id="submit_form" class="btn btn-default chci" style="background:#e94549;">UloÅ¾it</button>
                            </div>
                            <span id="error_message" class="text-danger"></span>
                            <span id="success_message" class="text-success"></span>
                            <div style="margin-top:10px;" id="success-messages"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12 pull-right"></div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my routes.php

```
      Route::post('/changepassword',['as'=>'changepassword','uses'=>'HomeController@changepassword']);
```

I am stuck into this problem and i dont know where i am doing wrong i have shared all details with you which will show you where i am doing wrong and why my popup form is not saving when i click on submit button its done nothing

Here your help will be highly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd advise to use the same structure in all your responses. What do you get in your `success` function?

Comment: `Network` tab in inspect element is your friend

Comment: i do get nothing

Comment: i go there on network tab but there is not showing anything

Comment: Please help me on this i am stuck

Answer (score 0):

try this, change `$(this).serialize()` instead `$('#password_change_form').serialize()`

```
    $('#submit_form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/changepassword",
        data: $('#password_change_form').serialize(),
        success: function(change_password) {
            alert(change_password);
        }
    });
}),
```

may it help you

Comment: add this syntax below `succes` on ajax, `,
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
      console.log(jqXHR);
    }` to know the error

Answer (score 0):

the DOM `<button>` doesnt trigger a submit event. put the event listener on the `<form>` instead.

```
$('#password_change_form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var saveThis = this;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/changepassword",
        data: $(saveThis).serialize(),
        success: function(change_password) {
            alert(change_password);
        }
    });
}),
```

in your controller, you dont need to do this

```
$errors = json_decode($errors); //line 7
```

`$validator->errors()` returns an `object` then you turn it into `string(json)` then you decode it back to `object` then in the return laravel turns it back to `string(json)`.

Comment: hi can we have chat?

Comment: @shahzadshah sure

Comment: can u invite me for chat

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181327/room-for-n69s-and-shahzad-shah